# How to prevent form from being activated when the users clicks on it?

Tags: delphi, winapi, c++builder, vcl

I have a main form and non-modal autocomplete form. How can I prevent the autocomplete form from being activated by the user, when the user clicks on the list in the autocomplete form?

So, basically I want the autocomplete form the receive the mouse click message when the users clicks, but to never become active, because it causes problems with a third-party component in the main form over which I have no control.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, riot_starter.  I hope you don't start any riots here!  Quick question.  Your question is tagged as both Delphi and C++ Builder.  Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using C++Builder, but since most people use Delphi instead, both solutions will be fine for me (I can convert the Delphi code to C++).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override CreateParams method of your form and add WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style to the extended styles.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;

  Params.WindowClass.ExStyle := Params.WindowClass.ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
end;
```

(code written from memory, might contain typos)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateParams` (Alex T. answer) or you can try set `YourForm.Enabled` to `False`.