# What should I do not to allow a window to be activated?

Tags: delphi, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent form from being activated when the users clicks on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500678/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-activated-when-the-users-clicks-on-it)

What I exactly mean, is that I want to create a popup window that exactly looks like a Tooltip window. I'm using `ShowWindow` and `SetWindowPos` to show and set its position. I already tried `SW_SHOWNOACTIVE` and it works perfect for the time when the popup appears; but when I click on the popup window, it gets focused, and I don't want this to happen. Also, when this popup is visible no matter it's focused or not, no message is sent to the window placed behind it.

I'm actually writing an Object Inspector component and for long values, it has to show a tooltip when mouse hovers a long value. I want this tooltip to look like a common one. I don't want to use Windows Tooltips not Delphi Tooltip directly. I want to use my own window.

P.S. I thought that this problem is common , and I searched, but I couldn't find an answer that exactly matches my question.

Thanks in advance.
Javid

Comment: Have you tried the `Enabled` property of the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to prevent form from being activated when the users clicks on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500678), related: [How to use window focus messages for a Delphi on-screen keyboard form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910278)

Comment: How do you make your tooltip window? Is it a derivative from TControl, or do you make it without the VCL?

Comment: You want to look your window like the common one, but refuse to use the common wnd... why is that, why do you want to roll your own?

Comment: None of those are things I'm looking for. Still one problem is remaining, and that is, I want the click message to be sent to the window, behind the tooltip.

Comment: Why do you say this is an exact duplicate? You should at least read the whole question, and then mark it as a duplicate! None of the mentioned questions are like my question.Thanks to `tomazy`.

Comment: @Javid - Until you posted a comment about the *"click message"*, the question was an exact duplicate since *"no message is sent to the window placed behind it"* did not make any sense at all. BTW you can also *upvote* tomazy's answer as a way of thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TMyTooltipWindow = class(TCustomControl)
private
  procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
protected
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
end;

procedure TMyTooltipWindow.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := WS_POPUP or WS_BORDER;
  Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
  Params.WindowClass.style := Params.WindowClass.style + CS_SAVEBITS;
end;

procedure TMyTooltipWindow.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

procedure TMyTooltipWindow.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  // this will make your window transparent for clicks 
  Message.Result := HTTRANSPARENT;
end;
```

This will not allow to activate the window with mouse.

Also having a look at **THintWindow** in Controls.pas might be helpful.